# Best way of storing documents to replicate folder structure in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a file mangement app and for that i want to replicate the folder structure in my firestore(i will  be storing the files in firebase storage) , i am confused between 2 ways ,

1. create two collections

   - Folders->Documents(folder)->name,id,owner,parent,childFoldes[][],childFiles[]
   - Files->Documents(file)->name ,owner ,parent,downloadUrl(of firebase storage)

this will look like this
[Document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu2Xs.png)

or the other way:

2. create a collection user->Document(Folder)->name,id,nestedFolderCollection,nestedFilesCollection

or the other way:

2. create a collection user->Document(Folder)->name,id,nestedFolderCollection,nestedFilesCollection

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I am trying to make a clone of google drive where currently my structure is ->i have a user collection inside which i have documents , and inside each user document i have two sub collections , Folders ,Files 
Now , Folders subcollection contains documents for each folder and link to its child folder/file in an array(using document id) and link to parent folder 
Also , File subcollection contains documents for each file and link to parent folder and firebase storage download url , things i am able to do till now is , create a folder/file

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific use-cases, I'd likely create a top-level users collection, and then under each user document have a single subcollection with a document for each file and filter (so without further nesting).

To then determine the hierarchy, give each file/folder document a parent ID and/or a path field that indicates its position in the directory tree.

Note this all depends on the actual use-case you want to implement through, which we (and likely even you) can't know up front. So I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video), start with a simple data model, and then be flexible in updating that data model as needed.